# org.apache.avro.UnresolvedUnionException: Not in union ["long","null"]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, avro

I have written this code to save a Spark dataframe into an avro file using Spark (1.3.0), Scala (2.10.4), and Spark Avro (1.0.0)

```
  def getMatchingLine(line: String) : Option[Row] = {
    val regex = "^.*&50=(\\w+)&.*&62-\\d=8&63-\\d=(\\w+)&.*timestamp=(\\d+).*$".r
    line match {
      case regex(a, b, c) => Some(Row(a, b, c))
      case _ => None
    }
  }

    val schema = StructType(List(StructField("a", StringType, true), StructField("b", StringType, true), StructField("c", LongType, true)))
    val rdd = sc.textFile(inputPath).cache()
    val rdd = rdd.map(getMatchingLine).filter(_.isDefined).flatMap(x => x)
    val df = sqlSc.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
    df.save("/user/foo/", "com.databricks.spark.avro")
```

The stack trace of the error message is

```
ion: org.apache.avro.UnresolvedUnionException: Not in union ["long","null"]: 1426647603695
        at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter.append(DataFileWriter.java:296)
        at org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroOutputFormat$1.write(AvroOutputFormat.java:169)
        at org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroOutputFormat$1.write(AvroOutputFormat.java:166)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkHadoopWriter.write(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1073)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1059)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:203)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to convert 3'd place in tuple to long. It's probably Integer, which can't be casted to Long.

Some(Row(a, b, (long)c))

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Row.html
looking at example shows that you can put any types..

maybe missing
 import org.apache.spark.sql._

Comment: it compiles now... I think intellij idea was just slow in compiling the source.